# Using OpenGL shaders for math calculation (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, opengl-es, shader

I have a matrix (for example 100x100 dimantion):
I need to do calculation with each element (`matrix[i,j]*tt/8+5` for example)

I have huge matrix and I want to implement the algorithm using OpenGL shaders. 
I want to use shader like:

```
uniform float val;
uniform float tt;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.x = val*tt/8+5
}
```

How I can implement the program? How I can get matrix after calculation(I do not want to show any windows\pictures?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a compute shader (rather than a vertex/fragment one). Compute shaders work much the same way, but they don't go through the graphics pipe.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be looking for [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or some such thing.

Comment: I looked for OpenCL (cross-platform and cross-vendors solution), but I should have runtime in this case. It will be one more dependency. 

I prefer to use OpenGL directly. Because my application already has the dependency.

Comment: Borgleader, Do you know how to get data after shaders processing in OpenGL?

Comment: For example [https://open.gl/content/code/c7_final.txt] How to get output matrix after glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4); ?

Comment: @Mike Smirnov: Shader Storage Buffers are designed to handle input/output in compute shaders. You have to learn some new concepts in order to use them correctly, however. Memory access order is not guaranteed and you need to implement this yourself.

Comment: 100x100 is not a "huge matrix". It would barely qualify as "big". You'd kill your performance just on having to transfer the data to the GPU and back.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible if you create a *fake* window frame buffer.

See my [sample program](https://github.com/skanti/Gaussian-Filter-GPU-OpenGL) where I abused the **fragment Shader** as a **compute Shader** because **compute shaders** are quite new. This program does some Gaussian Filtering calculations of the matrix and returns it to the CPU. (It actually does not matter what it does).

Here are few things to note:

- the transporting of files between CPU/GPU is slow
- other people already pointed out that your matrix is **NOT** huge. I consider it as very very small (it even fits in the RAM).