# Simplest way to use GPU in Java

Tags: java, gpu, bigdecimal

I have a java process with some basic operations with `BigDecimal`, and it runs millions of times, and I was thinking about using the idle capacity of the server's GPU, in parallel with other `String` operations on the CPU for better performance.
I wonder if there is a generic/simple way to consume this idle GPU for math operations.

I mean generic, because the server can change.

HP server with Matrox G200eh card.

Sample code:

```
BigDecimal bdTest = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal bdSum = bdTest.add(new BigDecimal(20));
...
```

Comment: That card is not a GPU in the modern sense. It's basically the weakest possible card to drive the physical graphics output of a server that's almost never used (i.e. mostly for debugging when things go really bad). The first G200 was released in 1998! There is effectively no compute capacity on that thing and it's highly unlikely that it actually provides the necessary drivers to be able to use it for compute. On this kind of hardware, stay on the CPU, it's significantly better at the general compute jobs.

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045419/using-opengl-shaders-for-math-calculation-c since its obsolete it doesn't have compute capabilities (OpenCL) but there are some tricks, such as is used with WebGL, to squeeze out some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aparapi](https://aparapi.com/) for GPU computations, but you cannot use BigDecimal.

Alternatively you can use [Apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) (arbitrary precision library) instead of BigDecimal. Apfloat should be faster but again - you cannot use it with Aparapi.

Here is an example of multiplying numbers from two arrays with Aparapi:

```java
final float[] arrayA = new float[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
final float[] arrayB = new float[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
final float[] result = new float[arrayA.length];
final float[] aparapiResult = new float[arrayA.length];

/* Normal */
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arrayA[i] * arrayB[i];
}

/* Aparapi */
Kernel kernel = new Kernel() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = getGlobalId();
        aparapiResult[i] = arrayA[i] * arrayB[i];
    }
};
Range range = Range.create(aparapiResult.length);
kernel.execute(range);
```

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aparapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>aparapi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Repeating that calculations 100 000 times for arrays with 1 000 000 elements, first "normal" snippet takes 1:15 while Aparapi snippet takes 0:24, on my machine.